# directional derivatives in (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've this function : $f(x,y)= \dfrac{(1+x^2)x^2y^4}{x^4+2x^2y^4+y^8}$ for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$

It's admits directional derivatives at the origin?

Answer (score 2):

A directional derivative needs a direction. Maybe you travel vertically straight through $(0,0)$, along the line $x=0$. Then your function is constantly $0$, so of course that particular directional derivative exists.

Otherwise, travel in the direction of the line $y=kx$. Then away from $(0,0)$ your function is $$f(x)=\frac{k^4(1+x^2)x^6}{x^4+2k^4x^6+k^8x^8}=\frac{k^4(1+x^2)x^2}{1+2k^4x^2+k^8x^4}$$ which is either identically $0$ if $k=0$, or otherwise is quadratic in nature as $x\to0$. In both cases, the derivative is $0$ at $x=0$.

So all directional derivatives for this function exist at $(0,0)$, and they are all equal to $0$.

---

Note though what happens if you approach $(0,0)$ along the nonlinear path $x=y^2$...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\nu=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ be any vector in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let us calculate the limit (which will depend on alpha) which is the d.d. with respect to $\nu$ of $f$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(t\cos\alpha,t\sin\alpha)}{t}=\lim\frac{(1+t^2\cos^2\alpha)t^6\cos^2\alpha\sin^4\alpha}{(t^2\cos^2\alpha+t^4\sin^4\alpha)^2t}.$$
By an asymptotic relationship I can get rid of the $t^2$ term above and of the $t^4$ term below, since they go to 0 faster than the rest. Si the limit above is the following:
$$\lim\frac{t^6\cos^2\alpha\sin^4\alpha}{t^4\cos^4\alpha\cdot t}=\lim t\frac{\cos^2\alpha\sin^4\alpha}{\cos^4\alpha}=0.$$
Remember the limit is for $t\to0$. So not only do *all* d.d.'s exist, but they are also all equal to $\nabla f(0,0)\cdot\nu$, where $\cdot$ is the scalar product. Is it my impression, or this implies the function is *differentiable* in the origin? And has the zero function as its differential? Well that *is* interesting. This means the converse of the total differential theorem is not true, since the theorem states that if the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood of a point and are continuous at that point then the function is differentiable at that point, and here we have a function with derivatives that exist in the neighborhood but are not continuous at the point and yet is differentiable. Which makes us wonder: is there any necessary and sufficient condition to differentiability?

**Update:**
No, the function is not differentiable, nor even continuous, at the origin. So having all d.d.s and them being equal to gradient times direction versor doesn't imply differentiability. I wonder how I could have thought that. The function is not continuous because approaching from $y=\sqrt x$ we get the limit of $\frac{(1+x^2)x^2x^2}{(x^2+x^2)^2}=\frac{(1+x^2)x^4}{4x^4}=\frac{1+x^2}{4}$, and that limit, for $x\to0$ is $\frac14\neq0$.

And now the dollar that was previously missing is in place, and you can read this update at last :).

Comment: Note: observe that $x^2+2x^2y^4+y^8=(x^2+y^4)^2$ to get the first expression for the limit.

Comment: Also, I tend to forget the ${}-f(0,0)$ part, but it is irrelevant in our case since $f(0,0)=0$ by definition.

Comment: It's not differentiable at $(0,0)$ because it's not even continuous there. You are right that all directional derivatives exist. It's just not enough to imply differentiability.

Comment: You're right @alex.jordan.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

A function admits directional derivative at a point if its gradient $\nabla{f}$ exists at that point. The gradient of your function is given by,
$$\nabla{f}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -\frac{2\, x\, y^4\, \left(2\, x^6 + 3\, x^4 - 2\, y^4 + 1\right)}{{\left(x^6 + x^2 + 2\, y^4\right)}^2} & \frac{4\, x^2\, y^3\, \left(x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1\right)}{{\left(x^6 + x^2 + 2\, y^4\right)}^2} \end{array}\right)$$
which doesn't exist at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, i.e. the origin, since you have $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined.

Comment: False. Partial derivatives are particular directional derivatives, and if calculated by their definitions at least $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists, and is 0. That is because if is the limit for $h\to0$ of $f(h,0)/h$ which is 0 for all $h$. A similar argument applies to the other partial derivative, which is also 0. So the gradient exists and is $(0,0)$. The only issue is whether the gradient's limit approaching the origin is or is not the gradient in the origin. If that doesn't hold, the function may not be differentiable, and then who knows about the other directional derivatives.

Comment: Also the function is continuous at the origin, as a side note, since its limit is 0 and it is defined to be 0 in the origin. If I prove the derivatives are continuous, by the theorem of the total differential the function is differentiable. Effectively the derivative you calculated is not continuous, I mean the one with respect to $x$. But then neither is the other one. So all one can do about the d.d.'s is to calculate each and every one of them by hand. What a pain in the bleep :).

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't agree with you about the fact that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists for the given point $(0,0)$

Comment: Note: the formula given for the derivatives is because $f(0,0)=0$, otherwise I would have had $\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$ and similarly for the other derivative.

Comment: Well let's use the definition, shall we? If I remember well, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$. In our case, this reduces to $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{(1+h^2)h\cdot0}{h^2+2h^2\cdot0^4+0^8}= \lim\frac{0}{h\cdot h^2}=0$, or am I missing something fundamental? Anyway, is there anything wrong in my answer below? That gives all d.d.'s the same value: 0.

Comment: The fact you can't plug in $(0,0)$ to your expression of the partial derivatives doesn't imply they don't exist. And the non-existence of the gradient doesn't imply the function has _no_ d.d.'s, it could have some but not all, for all I know. After all, the proof that the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\nu$ at $P$ is the product $\nabla f(P)\cdot\nu$ only works when the gradient exists, doesn't it?

Comment: And if you still don't agree, point out an error in my arguments or give your own argument against what I state, @user72272. Do, please :). I might be missing something and making a terrible mistake, so please speak up :).

Comment: @MickG This function is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Approach via $x=y^2$ to see.